# Debugging Vue TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Whilst writing Vue tests I often come across the error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

This error is typically because a `prop` is not defined on a (potentially child) component

My current method of debugging this is to check all the components down the tree and see if I can figure out which prop isn't set, which isn't targeted or very efficient.

Is there a good way to hone in on which value is undefined and debug this faster?